# How to grab data on website?

Tags: php, screen-scraping

So, often, I check my accounts for different numbers. For example, my affiliate accounts: I check for cash increase.

I want to program a script where it can login to all these websites and then grab the money value for me and display it on one page. How can I program this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should take a look into [curl](http://jp.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php). 
You should be able to generate a script that retrieve some webpage easily.

Also take a look into [simplexml](http://jp.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) and [dom](http://jp.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php), it would help you to extract information from (X)HTML files.

Also [Zend_Http](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.http.html) could be a good alternative to curl.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Well, sort of a vague question... I'd suggest the following steps:

- send the login credentials via POST
- grab and parse the response
- do this for all relevant accounts / sites you wanna check

if you face specific problems feel free to comment on this answer

EDIT: I'd agree to RageZ in his technical approach. curl would be the 'weapon of choice' for me too... ^^

hth

K

Answer (score 0):

First of all, check if the services where you want to log in have APIs.
It's be much easier as that's a format specifically made for the purpose of getting the datas and exploiting them in an other application.

If there is an API, you can look at it's documentation to see how to retrieve and use the datas.

If there isn't any, you need to scrap the HTML pages.
You can start by taking a look at Curl : http://php.net/curl 
The idea is to simulate your own visit of the website by sending the loggin post request and getting the given datas.

After retrieving the page's datas, you can parse them with tools like dom.
http://php.net/dom

Answer (score 0):

Use [TestPlan](http://testplan.brainbrain.net/), it was designed as a web automation system and makes such tasks very simple.

Answer (score 0):

I would really have a look into [Snoopy](http://sourceforge.net/projects/snoopy/) if i were you, its more user friendly than curl to use in your PHP scripts. Here is some [sample code](http://www.jonasjohn.de/snippets/php/snoopy-example.htm).

```
<?php
    /*
    You need the snoopy.class.php from 
    http://snoopy.sourceforge.net/
    */

    include("snoopy.class.php");

    $snoopy = new Snoopy;

    // need an proxy?:
    //$snoopy->proxy_host = "my.proxy.host";
    //$snoopy->proxy_port = "8080";

    // set browser and referer:
    $snoopy->agent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)";
    $snoopy->referer = "http://www.jonasjohn.de/";

    // set some cookies:
    $snoopy->cookies["SessionID"] = '238472834723489';
    $snoopy->cookies["favoriteColor"] = "blue";

    // set an raw-header:
    $snoopy->rawheaders["Pragma"] = "no-cache";

    // set some internal variables:
    $snoopy->maxredirs = 2;
    $snoopy->offsiteok = false;
    $snoopy->expandlinks = false;

    // set username and password (optional)
    //$snoopy->user = "joe";
    //$snoopy->pass = "bloe";

    // fetch the text of the website www.google.com:
    if($snoopy->fetchtext("http://www.google.com")){ 
        // other methods: fetch, fetchform, fetchlinks, submittext and submitlinks

        // response code:
        print "response code: ".$snoopy->response_code."<br/>\n";

        // print the headers:

        print "<b>Headers:</b><br/>";
        while(list($key,$val) = each($snoopy->headers)){
            print $key.": ".$val."<br/>\n";
        }

        print "<br/>\n";

        // print the texts of the website:
        print "<pre>".htmlspecialchars($snoopy->results)."</pre>\n";

    }
    else {
        print "Snoopy: error while fetching document: ".$snoopy->error."\n";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use VietSpider Web Data Extractor.

VietSpider Web Data Extractor: Software crawls the data from the websites (Data Scraper), format to XML standard (Text, CDATA) then store in the relational database.Product supports the various of RDBMs such as Oracle, MySQL, SQL Server, H2, HSQL, Apache Derby, Postgres ...VietSpider Crawler supports Session (login, query by form input), multi downloading, JavaScript handling, Proxy (and multi proxy by auto scan the proxies from website),...

Download from http://binhgiang.sourceforge.net